# Tree view of node under taxonomy

Tags: 7, views, theming, taxonomy-terms

Hi I am facing a serious problem to list all nodes/subterms under each terms. Let's say I have several terms.

```
Games
   -> Cricket
   -> Football
   -> Badminton
   -> Tennis
     -> Long Tennis
     -> Table Tennis
   -> Hocky
```

Here you can see Games is the top most categories and Cricket, Football etc are sub categories. Must note: Tennis has 2 sub categories.

Each last term has some contents. That means Football, Cricket all are have several contents. But Tennis don't have any content. Long Tennis and Table Tennis has contents.

My aim is to show all the 1st level categories (That means Cricket, Football, Badminton, Tennis, Hocky) and then show all content under taxonomy term tree.

Like this below:

```
Categories: 
   -> Cricket
   -> Football
   -> Badminton
   -> Tennis
   -> Hocky

Football:
   How to play Football?
   Football ground measurement.
   What is Football

Badminton:
   How to play Badminton?
   Badminton ground measurement.
   What is Badminton

Tennis:
  Long Tennis:
      How to play Tennis?
      Tennis ground measurement.
      What is Tennis
  Table Tennis:
      How to play Table Tennis?
      Table Tennis ground measurement.
      What is Tennis

Hocky:
   How to play Hocky?
   Hocky ground measurement.
   What is Hocky
```

I tried with Taxonomy View but no success. Tried to create the taxonomy-term.tpl.php file but I failed to give the display. I have modified the code many times so I can not paste the code here.

I am using Drupal 7 and views 3.

Is there any solution to solve this? Can you suggest me how can I achieve this? I think I am running on some wrong way. Please help me and give some advice to solve the things.

Lots of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [Views Tree](https://drupal.org/project/views_tree) module. Install the module and read the readme.txt file to implement the same. Do get back in case of any doubts.

Comment: Sorry sir, still unclear to me. How to configure the module? I can not see any configuration. I checked the documentation also but this is unclear to me

Comment: By default you want to show the categories (Cricket, football ...). and when clicking football you want to show the items in football . I am getting it clear.